# How to get values on click from table row and show it in input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, return-value

Here I have a gviz table with data: http://jsbin.com/OJAnaji/9 and CODE: http://jsbin.com/OJAnaji/9/edit

I also create an modal window with input fields. Now I want when I click on table row to show row data into input fields in modal window... How I can do that?

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Edit selected row</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add new row</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
  <input type="text" id-"name" class="form-control" placeholder="Type name">
        </div></br>
        <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Gender</span>
  <input type="text" id="gender" class="form-control" placeholder="Gender?">
</div></br>
        <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Age</span>
  <input type="text" id="age" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of age">
</div></br>
        <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Donuts eaten</span>
  <input type="text" id="donuts_eaten" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of donuts eaten">
</div></br>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

So:
1.user click on table row
2.user click on button "Edit row"
3.User get values from row to input fields

Is this possible to do ?

*sorry for my english its bad but i'm learning hard*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/INenUhEM/1), this is partially working i.e. only for table rows with white background. Change necessary things to get it worked for all rows.

Answer (score 1):

because im not familiar with the code of yours i will write a code i think will suit you and add some comments to make it more clear and you tell me if you need something else.

```
$("#YourTableId tbody tr").click(function () {
    //this = the row a user has clicked
    var storedNameInTable = $(this).find("#name").text(); // will get the label with id = name from the same row a user has clicked
    $("#name").val(storedNameInTable); //will take the name and put it on the textbox.
    var self = this;        //saves the row scope
    $("#SaveChanges").click(function () {
        var NameAfterChange = $("#name").val();  //takes the newly changed name
        $(self).find("#name").text(NameAfterChange);  //puts it in the table
        $("#SaveChanges").unbind("click");  //make sure you want call this button again so you want have more than 1 click event
    });
});
```